# How APNS detect Device is online / offline /switch of

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have read APNS cache last notification for some time if device is offline/switch off state. My question is how APNS identify device status ?

Answer (score 1):

The APNS service on the iOS device maintains a [persistent connection](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203609) to Apple's servers. When a push message arrives at Apple's servers for a device it is delivered over that connection.

If the destination device is not currently connected when a push arrives then Apple holds that message. If the same app sends another push to the same device then the new push is held and the previous one is lost.

When the iOS device finally reconnects to the network and Apple's server, held pushes are delivered.

Comment: As you mention "iOS device maintains a persistent connection to Apple's servers". It means all devices are connected to Apple server all the time and I am wondering how many apple server port is open? . When ever new iPhone is comes into picture it open new port on Apple server, is this correct ?

Comment: The connections that an Apple device makes are described in this document - https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203609